# What is equivalent programming code for closing and opening android app manually?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have tried following list of code that are available ,but none of them kills all activity after relaunching the app. How to relaunch an app killing all past activities ,just like closing app and opening app manually

```
AlarmManager alm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alm.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 3000,     
PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, this.getClass()), 0));

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)
```

if I use below code it just crashes entire app as well

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: "How to relaunch an app killing all past activities ,just like closing app and opening app manually" -- that is an anti-pattern in Android app development. You should revisit why you are seeking to do this and find some other solution for whatever problem you are experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I know of that you can get to closing and reopening the app again is:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivityClass.class);

intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will clear the activity stack and launch the specified new one (clearing it basicaly means that you can't go back to previous activity and its saved state).